# (Fixed) CiviCRM update on Joomla causes existing online registration pages to give 404 errors. What can I do to fix it?

Tags: joomla, upgrade

I moved my Joomla based site to another host with better PHP and DB support.   Used Akeeba Backup to restore the site, it came up properly.   I then upgraded to the latest version of CiviCRM as I now had the proper DB version to do so.

The upgrade looked like it went well, aside from the issue of the old version SQL files that I needed to delete causing a DB update error, and a time out issue.   Realized I needed to adjust the PHP settings.

However, when I go and test my online event registration form, it gives me a 404 error, not found.   Found out that the CiviCRM menu type was not available.    Did some snooping, and realized that the "elements" and "views" directories were not under the /components directory.    Decided to do what I was doing previously, and download the 'ALT' version of the CiviCRM Joomla update archive, then move the directories myself, then edit the XML file.

Ran the Joomla installer again, the CiviCRM menu type appeared with all the menu selections.   So I went to the event function, opened the event, saved everything, then added that page to the menu.

Tried to access ... 404.

I'm stumped :(

I was getting this error until I found and renamed the file under the media/civicrm/persist directory.

```
Jul 23 19:18:20  [error] Unexpected error while rendering a file in the AssetBuilder: Unrecognized asset name: crm-l10n.js
Array
(
    [exception] => Civi\Core\Exception\UnknownAssetException: "Unrecognized asset name: crm-l10n.js"
#0 /home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/AssetBuilder.php(192): Civi\Core\AssetBuilder->render("crm-l10n.js", (Array:10))
#1 /home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi/Core/AssetBuilder.php(135): Civi\Core\AssetBuilder->build("crm-l10n.js", (Array:10))
#2 /home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Resources/Common.php(218): Civi\Core\AssetBuilder->getUrl("crm-l10n.js", (Array:10))
#3 /home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Resources/Common.php(128): CRM_Core_Resources_Common::coreResourceList("html-header")
#4 /home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php(1164): CRM_Core_Resources_Common::createFullBundle("coreResources")
#5 /home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php(634): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->createService(Object(Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Definition), (Array:0), TRUE, "bundle.coreResources")
#6 /home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/dependency-injection/ContainerBuilder.php(588): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->doGet("bundle.coreResources", 1)
#7 /home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/Civi.php(114): Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder->get("bundle.coreResources")
#8 /home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Resources.php(214): Civi::service("bundle.coreResources")
#9 /home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm/CRM/Core/Resources.php(380): CRM_Core_Resources->addBundle("coreResources")
#10 /home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(102): CRM_Core_Resources->addCoreResources()
#11 /home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php(40): civicrm_invoke()
#12 /home/usafnu5/public_html/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(402): require_once("/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")
#13 /home/usafnu5/public_html/libraries/src/Component/ComponentHelper.php(377): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::executeComponent("/home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/components/com_civicrm/civicrm.php")
#14 /home/usafnu5/public_html/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php(101): Joomla\CMS\Component\ComponentHelper::renderComponent("com_civicrm")
#15 /home/usafnu5/public_html/libraries/src/Application/AdministratorApplication.php(159): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->dispatch()
#16 /home/usafnu5/public_html/libraries/src/Application/CMSApplication.php(203): Joomla\CMS\Application\AdministratorApplication->doExecute()
#17 /home/usafnu5/public_html/administrator/index.php(51): Joomla\CMS\Application\CMSApplication->execute()
#18 {main}

)
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Neil

Comment: Question #2:    If this is an error that can't easily be fixed, is it possible to uninstall CiviCRM without the uninstall deleting the data and tables??

Answer (score 0):

OK ... I haven't had to do this in a while, but I basically followed the troubleshooting steps in the SysAdmin Guide.

Not sure which did the trick but I rebuilt the triggers, then deleted the templates_c contents (which I do on upgrades anyway) but also deleted the Config.IDS.ini file, which I didn't do.

Anyway ... now the form appears and processes fine.